# Ajax request in visual studio

Tags: jquery, html, json, visual-studio-2013

I am writing a very very simple script in html to parse json data but I am not getting the output in the browser for the div element? Iam sure I am doing a stupid thing somewhere but not getting that.

**HTML,JS,JQUERY**

```
<h1>Ajax Hellow World</h1>

    <script type="text/javascript" >
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open("GET", "JSON/MyList.json", true);   
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json", true);
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                    var data = JSON.parse(xhr.response);
                    $('#results').html(data.user);
                        }
            }
            xhr.send(null);
            $('#results').html("Working...........");
        });     
    </script>
    <div id="results"></div>
```

MyList.json is located in JSON Folder.

**JSON File**

```
{ "user":"John", "Age":44, "Location":"LA" }
```

Comment: What are you getting? Are there any console errors? Does your `onreadystatechange` ever get called? If it does, is the `xhr.response` what you actually expect it to be?

Comment: Well for one thing, your JS and JQuery have an error. You need a semicolon after the `}` just above `xhr.send(null);`

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found).Sorry at first I did not see this.

Comment: @khan: Look at the network tab in your browser and see exactly what the *full* URL it's trying to hit is. Then try that same URL directly in your browser's address bar. I suspect you aren't hitting the URL you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is correct (Although as Chris Hawkes points out, you might better served using JQuery's totally awesome $.ajax() funciton).

Assuming you're using the Visual Studio debug server, your issue is that it's not configred with a static handler for the .json file type.

You need to add this to your web.config, inside the "<configuration>" tags.

```
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/JSON"/>
    </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```